# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2810/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for physics research
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/980).

Comment: I guess physicists don't really have a lot to advertise... I've been thinking about it but I didn't come up with any good examples. (Yet)

Comment: You've got a year to think of something. ♪

Comment: I find this question rather confusing.  Keep in mind, people are getting redirected here from clicking on the add, and probably thinking "what in the world?"

Comment: @Zassoun Thanks for prodding me about that - this is one of many sites where I haven't revised the description to something that actually makes sense. I'll get right to that, let me know if it is any clearer now.

Comment: @GraceNote Yes, that addresses it exactly!  A nice "about" right there directed to what they were looking for.

Answer (score 21):

[image: arXiv.org -- open access to over 700 000 e-prints]

Comment: Borrowed from math.SE

Answer (score 17):

[image: Chemistry - Stack Exchange]

Comment: I dont know why this is, but looking at this picture for the first time (and from afar) made me hungry :-P ... But now I like it ;-) +1

Comment: @Nemo when RichardT first posted it in our chat room, we all felt that way :P Jelly sandwich!

Comment: Ha ha, so I`m not the only one :-). It has a good potential to attract new users to Chemistry since it looks like this site offers something to eat ;-)

Comment: @nemo cool, new slogan for an ad... "Join chem.SE, we have fooood!" :p  Are you planning on joining? Even if you're not too good at chemistry, some nice questions would help us :)

Comment: I`ll see, my chemistry courses are a bit far away now ... ;-). Tomorrow I`ll be off on holidays for three weeks :-P and not sure how often I`ll be online then ... Of course, to the Chemistry site should NOT happen what happend to Astronomy and TP for example ... :-/

Comment: Sorry to sound pedantic, but it's Chemistry Stack Exchange with a space in between the two words. Even though the logos may appear to be styled in CamelCase all SE sites (including SO, SF, AU etc.) are spelt out as two words, not one

Comment: @Yi alright, I'll forward that to Fx

Comment: @YiJiang fixed…

Comment: For some background on this image, this is an isosurface representation of the highest occupied molecular orbital of the benzene molecule (C6H6). The electronic structure calculation was performed using the ORCA software of Neese and coworkers, was post-processed in VMD and then rendered in Blender using Cycles. The isosurface meshes are not strictly quantitative as they were Catmull-Clark subdivided and smoothed. Red is wild cherry flavoured and blue is blueberry flavoured. :D

Answer (score 15):

[image: Contribute to a Physics Wikibook]

Comment: Here's the original [SVG file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1187749/WikibooksPhysicsLogo/WikibooksPhysics.svg), if anyone wants to make a better version.

Answer (score 13):

[image: INSPIRE -- literature database search for high-energy physics]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Hi! Academia.SE has a nicely growing community discussing all sorts of matters relating to academic life, from grad student to emeritus professor… We think it could be of interest to a good part of the Physics.SE community!

Answer (score 11):

[image: Mathematica at Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Why String Theory? A Layman's Journey to the Frontiers of Physics]

Comment: A bit of detail about the site. It's a educational site sponsored by the Royal Society and University of Oxford, providing a good amount of detail about current string theory research. Hopefully it's accessibly to the layman, but also contains sufficient information to interest students at undergraduate level.

Comment: If you like this site you may also enjoy browsing  http://superstringtheory.com

Comment: @Qmechanic: that's true. Although I think Why String Theory? is a little more up to date! The superstrings one doesn't look like it's changed since the 90s. Still a useful reference though :).

Comment: Ha ha yep, of course I like this ... ;-P...+1. Would be fun if it gets enough upvotes to get featured, LOL :-D

Comment: Wow, I have just seen that you have worked yourself on developing this cute site? It is a lot of fun browsing through it :-). There is only one link to a not particularly ST friendly blog I dont agree with; the owner of this blog will certainly not approve this nice site you (helped to ?) developped. As soon as he detects it he will most probably write a blog post ... but not with the intent to advertise it, on the contrary ... :-/

Comment: @Dilaton I did work on it myself, thanks for the compliments! I agree that Peter Woit is probably not going to be positive about the site. But our brief was to provide a balanced overview of string theory, so it's only fair to link to some more critical material. I myself don't agree with Peter either, but that's just my personal viewpoint!

Comment: Dear Edward, the overview is very fair and balanced indeed I think, it makes a very nice and enjoyable reading and there is partly even some good humor in it that made me chuckle :-). I'm so sorry that in the comments below Sean Carrol's article announcing the cute site many people including PW (he is horribly unfair, scornful, and destructive in my opinion) just spit and spat on it. I just hope you, Charlotte Mason, and Joseph Conlon manage to ignore them (if you have seen this :-/...) and that you generally obtain the positive response you deserve to your cool project. Cheers

Comment: @EdwardHughes Can you repost your answer [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2810/5724) too ...?

Answer (score 7):

[image: Wikipedia Science Reference Desk]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Space Exploration and Technology]