# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for physics research
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2810).

Answer (score 19):

[image: arXiv.org -- open access to over 800 000 e-prints]

Comment: Is it really _still_ necessary to promote arXiv.org?

Comment: @Claudius: If you don't think so, downvote the proposal... :)

Comment: Don’t worry, I did :)

Comment: @Claudius it was never _necessary_ to promote arXiv.org. They get plenty of traffic from established researchers already. That's not why the ad was here. It's here to give people who wouldn't already know about it (non-researchers) a window into this important pillar of the research community.

Comment: why don't you advertise BOINC instead? http://boinc.berkeley.edu/download.php
It would sure be useful for scientific progress.
(Though I personally dislike the SETI program, there are just so many others to choose instead)

Comment: @Raindrop: If you feel so, just make an ad and post it :)

Comment: @Claudius I think it's a good reminder for people to check it out

Answer (score 18):

[image: Chemistry - Stack Exchange]

Comment: I may get this one revamped later :)

Comment: I really like this one because it looks like some kind of jelly donut :) It's one of the few "ads" that has ever caught my attention. (I guess it'd be a benzene donut actually...)

Comment: Looking at the profiles here, Mannishearth is the only person I've come across that subscribes to chem.se. So I guess most users would find its presence here an annoying distraction.

Comment: @LarryHarson Sure, possibly. But in this case it's been upvoted enough, so a significant portion of the community wants it. As mentioned elsewhere on this page (I think), we don't delete answers based on "unsuitability" unless they're NSFW or something. (Also, people click this ad according to [stats](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2810), so it's not ignored)

Comment: I think both sites would benefit from more interaction. There are some quantum questions there that would be answered quite well by users here, and there are some questions here that would also be on-topic over there. In my opinion, not enough Physics.SE users know about Chem.SE.

Answer (score 18):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Comment: This looks really cool :D Who made the ad?

Comment: @Manishearth - It's my own musings, and perhaps still a work in progress. I started with [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dHKpf.png), then [added the gas giants](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t253k.png), then realized it might be too dark, so I added a few more things to it. There is still room for improvement tho, when I'll find the time to fiddle with it some more... :)

Comment: Niiice :) You ought to peddle your image-making arts on the other SE sites needing community ads.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Comment: Hey, your add is public! Congrats.

Answer (score 7):

[image: writeLaTeX.com - great for explaining physics, and works on your iPad too!]

Comment: This is an ad from TeX SX, which may also be useful here and on Math SX for a couple of reasons: you can use it to collaborate in real time to help explain physics (especially when there's maths involved), and secondly, it is a great option for working through problems on an iPad or other tablet (for which there are limited alternatives). Happy to let the community vote decide - I'm one of the developers of writeLaTeX, so any feedback appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[image: BOINC volunteer distributed computing]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Mathematica at Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Astrobites]

Answer (score 6):

[image: MIT Open Courseware]

Answer (score 3):

[image: SciFi & Fantasy]

Comment: I do like this one

Comment: Thank you muchly :)

Comment: please put a tiny text maybe at the bottom right of the picture saying 'scifi stackexchange'...

Comment: Do we need to advertise Sci - Fi . SE? This is a physics site!

Comment: sci fiction and fantasy, you're kidding, right?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Why String Theory? A Layman's Journey to the Frontiers of Physics]

Comment: Which rascals have downvoted this ...?!

Comment: @Dilaton: I didn't downvote, but I don't think this ad is good (after all, it's linking to a popular-science site). It could be supplemented with links to good non-popular resources. Or it could link to that "Official Superstring theory" thing which has both popular and semi-popular.

Comment: @Dimension10 yes, it links to a rather popular site but it was set up by students of a quite serious physicist. [Lumo](http://motls.blogspot.de/2012/10/miracles-prove-divine-power-of-string.html) thought too it is quite cute and the only thing I disaprove is a link to a troll site it contains for political correctness ;-). And certain parts could/should be updated ... Do you have an idea for an add of a more technical site such as the official one?

Comment: @Dilaton: When you said "official one", I didn't realise at first that  you were talking about the Official Superstring theory website,  I thought that this website here was "unnoficial" and there was an official version. : )

Comment: @Dilaton: And some sentences are wrong. E.g. it says that the critical dimension of 10 is due to "making it consistent with SR." I presume they mean Lorentz invariance, then it would be very much of a half-truth. It only is the reason in LCG (not LQG)  quantisation but you could always chose the canonical method of quantisation, then it would be to    remove the Pauli - Villar 
  ghost states.

Comment: @Dimension10 Ouch ... :-/!

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS: that sentence isn't wrong. As you say yourself - the critical dimension emerges by requiring Lorentz invariance in the light cone gauge quantization. In other words, making the theory consistent with the axioms of special relativity. Sure, if you quantize canonically then it's to get rid of the Pauli-Villar states. I can't really think of a way of explaining that to the layman in a sentence though...

Answer (score 3):

[image: INSPIRE -- literature database search for high-energy physics]

Comment: Oh, heh, I thought it was already here. Thanks :-)

Comment: I honestly can't see the point of this suggestion since most researchers already know about this.

Comment: @Dimension10 So how is the site of use to the average student here?

Comment: Can you give an example of when a student might want to use it?

Answer (score 3):

[image: KhanAcademy]

Answer (score 2):

[image: TED (Technology, Entertainment, Design)]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Some explanation, please?

Comment: @EugeneSeidel That's an open archive similar to Arxiv (they are sisters by the way) with a few more features. You can upload your PhD dissertation, Lecture notes as well even though preprints are the main targets.

Comment: I have  changed the size of the image to be 2200*250 (as per the img requirements). I hope you're ok. If you're not, you could just revert the editr.

Answer (score -3):

[image: SciFi & Fantasy]

Comment: Do we need to promote SciFi.SE on a physics site? (Ignoring the fact that the caption applies to any body with a gravitational field).

Comment: @Dimension10 It is the phone booth that "the Doctor" in the Dr. Who television series uses to travel between planets, stars, epochs and dimensions. Step inside and you will see that it is indeed much bigger :) You can argue that non-science sites should not be promoted here and you would have a valid argument. On the other hand, many scientists enjoy SF as a diversion. A number of SF authors have been scientists (e.g., Asimov). And a not insignificant number of scientists were turned on as youngsters to the wonders of the natural world by reading about distant stars and galaxies in a SF novel.

Comment: I can't imagine anyone from here wanting to click on this.